# How do I solve the error "Invalid feature flag configuration" when running my React native app with AWS backend?

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

When attempting to run any amplify command, such as amplify console, I receive the following error.

```
Invalid feature flag configuration

These feature flags are defined in the "amplify/cli.json" configuration file and are unknown to the currently running Amplify CLI:
  - graphqltransformer.securityenhancementnotification
  - graphqltransformer.showfieldauthnotification

This issue likely happens when the project has been pushed with a newer version of Amplify CLI, try updating to a newer version.

Learn more about feature flags: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/feature-flags
```

How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message there is a mismatch between the versions of Amplify CLI. To fix this, update the Amplify CLI version used during the build phase:

1. Log in to your AWS console
2. Search for the AWS Amplify service
   [image: search]
3. Select your Amplify app from the list
   [image: Select your app]
4. On the left, under **app settings**, click on **build settings**
   [image: Build settings]
5. Scroll down to the **edit build image settings** section and press the **Edit** button
   [image: Edit build image]
6. Add a Live package update by choosing package = "Amplify CLI" and version = "latest"
   [image: Live Package update]
7. Finally, Save and try to rebuild

Comment: If you can include the screenshots, I think that will help understanding the points that you listed.

Comment: @HAK Screenshots added, for now I can only post them as links as it requires more reputation to add images directly